# Efficient computation of $\sum_{i=1}^{\sqrt{n}} i^2\cdot\left\lfloor{\frac n{i^2}}\right\rfloor$

Tags: sequences-and-series, computational-number-theory, sums-of-squares

I need to compute efficiently the sum 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\sqrt{n}} i^2\cdot\left\lfloor{\frac n{i^2}}\right\rfloor.
$$

We can do this in  $O({\sqrt{n}})$ but I need a faster algorithm: for example, it would be fine an algorithm of complexity $O(\sqrt[3]{n})$ (cube root in time) or $O(\log n)$ whatever, but however less than the square root in time.

edit1:

So far what i have got
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\sqrt{n}} i^2\cdot\left\lfloor{\frac n{i^2}}\right\rfloor= n *\left \lfloor {\sqrt{n}} \right \rfloor - \sum_{i=1}^{i=\left \lfloor {\sqrt{n}} \right \rfloor} n \mod i^{2}
$$

Now how can we efficiently compute 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{i=\left \lfloor {\sqrt{n}} \right \rfloor} n \mod i^{2}
$$

edit2:

We can look at it by taking
$\left\lfloor\frac{N}{i^2}\right\rfloor=1$ whenever $1\leq\frac{N}{i^2}<2$. So whenever $\sqrt{N}\geq i>\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}$. There are $\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}\right\rfloor$ such values of $i$.Now how can $i^2$ can be multiplied to the above terms.

Comment: This seems to be an active question on codechef competition. It has been flooding math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following by comment of Alexey Kulikov we could split our sum in the next way:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{[\sqrt{n}]} i^2\left [\frac{n}{i^2}\right ]=
\sum_{[n/i^2]>[\sqrt[3]{n}]} i^2\left [\frac{n}{i^2}\right ]+\sum_{[n/i^2]\leq [\sqrt[3]{n}]} i^2\left [\frac{n}{i^2}\right ]=$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{\left [\sqrt{\frac{n}{[\sqrt[3]{n}]+1}}\right ]} i^2\left [\frac{n}{i^2}\right ]+\sum_{j=1}^{[\sqrt[3]{n}]} j \sum_{i=[\sqrt{n/(j+1)}]+1}^{[\sqrt{n/j}]} i^2,$$
while last sum can be computed effectively:
 $$\sum_{i=[\sqrt{n/(j+1)}]+1}^{[\sqrt{n/j}]} i^2=\sum_{i=1}^{[\sqrt{n/j}]} i^2-\sum_{i=1}^{[\sqrt{n/(j+1)}]} i^2=$$ $$=\frac{1}{6}\left (\left[ \sqrt{\frac{n}{j}}\right ]*\left (\left[ \sqrt{\frac{n}{j}} \right ] +1\right ) *\left (2\left[\sqrt{\frac{n}{j}}\right ] +1\right ) - \left[ \sqrt{\frac{n}{j+1}}\right ]*\left (\left[ \sqrt{\frac{n}{j+1}}\right ] +1\right ) *\left (2\left[ \sqrt{\frac{n}{j+1}}\right ] +1\right )  \right ).$$